# Unrecognized selector sent to instance, reason: '-[UITouchesEvent rightView]

Tags: swift, unrecognized-selector

My app crashes and throws this error

```
[UITouchesEvent rightView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13d5092e0
2016-08-04 17:07:15.569 [3809:1375151] 

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITouchesEvent rightView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13d5092e0'

*** First throw call stack:
(0x180d72db0 0x1803d7f80 0x180d79c4c 0x180d76bec 0x180c74c5c 0x1000e681c 0x1000e6a60 0x185f08be8 0x185f08b64 0x185ef0870 0x185f11360 0x185f07ed8 0x185f00c20 0x185ed104c 0x185ecf628 0x180d2909c 0x180d28b30 0x180d26830 0x180c50c50 0x182538088 0x185f3a088 0x1000f5c88 0x1807ee8b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I'm trying to make a custom class for hide and show password so that I can use it in any `UITextField` in any `UIViewController`.

```
class HideShowIcon:NSObject {

    var showPasswordImage = UIImage(named: "ic_show_password") as UIImage?
    var hidePasswordImage = UIImage(named: "ic_hide_password") as UIImage?


    func hideShowPasswordButton(hideText:UITextField) {

        var hideShowSize: CGSize = "12345".sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0)])
        var hideShow: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
        hideShow.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: hideShowSize.width, height: hideText.frame.size.height)
        hideShow.setImage(hidePasswordImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        hideText.rightView = hideShow
        hideText.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
        hideShow.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HideShowIcon.hideShowPasswordTextField(_:hideText:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.AllTouchEvents)

    }
    func hideShowPasswordTextField(sender: AnyObject,hideText:UITextField) {

        var hideShow: UIButton = (hideText.rightView as? UIButton)!
        if !hideText.secureTextEntry {
            hideText.secureTextEntry = true

            hideShow.setImage(hidePasswordImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        } else {
            hideText.secureTextEntry = false
            hideShow.setImage(showPasswordImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
        hideText.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use selector with many parameters `hideShowPasswordTextField(_:hideText:)` for `UIButton` target. You can only use selector with one (or zero) parameter, in which `UIButton` will put itself: `hideShowPasswordTextField(_:)`

```
func hideShowPasswordTextField(sender: UIButton) {
    //...
}
```

To use `hideText` in this function, you may declare it as property of your class:

```
var hideText: UITextField!
```

and assign value to it in class initialization step

Comment: On doing this, while clicking the hide and show image button, I'm able to see the text on long pressing the button for hide and show. On clicking once and leaving, text goes back to hidden state

Comment: Thank you . It works. I had to change UIControlEvents.AllTouchEvents to touchUpInside